# C++: How are pointers themselves handled regarding memory management?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a fairly simple question;
I have arrays which contain pointers to objects. I sometimes create mutated arrays from those arrays and only use them, let's say, within a method. Aftwards I don't need them. In this case I don't want the pointed data to be destroyed as I keep using the original Array. What I don't fully understand is what happens to the pointers ( not the data itself, but the pointers) that were created in my temporarily Array? How does Memory deal with them.  As far as I know Pointers can only point to an address. You can't "delete" them.

Anyone who can give me more insight? All this time I feel like I'm doing something wrong with memory.

In this case list is my "bag", which is an object wrapper for an array implementation. However since it contains gabs between indexes I use getGapless to get a bag where the nullptr indexes are excluded.

I delete my bag at the end, but it doesn't delete the actual content ( that is done with a different method ).

So when do those pointers in my "players" bag go out of scope?

```
virtual void processEntities(artemis::ImmutableBag<artemis::Entity*>& bag)
{
    artemis::Bag<artemis::Entity*> * list  = (artemis::Bag<artemis::Entity*>*)this->world->getGroupManager()->getEntities("HUMAN");
    if(list == nullptr) return;//Kill function

    artemis::Bag<artemis::Entity*> * players = list->getGapless();

    for(int i=0; i<players->getCount(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j < players->getCount(); j++)
        {
            if(intersects(*players->get(i),*players->get(j))){
                std::cout << "Collide YEAH \n";
            }
        }
    }
    delete players;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, don't worry! You can think of pointers as being managed in the same way as `int`s or `double`s (at least in terms of memory). The pointer itself is like an `int` that happens to contain the address of some other object or array of objects. Once the pointer disappears from scope, the memory for the pointer itself will automatically be recovered.

The exception would be if you're doing something like `int** p = new int*[1]`, i.e. creating pointers with `new`. Then you will at some point need to `delete p`.

If you're creating your pointers like `int* p = new int[size];` (which is probably what you want), then `p` itself is on the **stack**, which means you don't need to concern yourself with memory deallocation, but the array `p` points to is on the **heap** which means you will need to deallocate it at some point.

Comment: I know that deleting the data itself is a must in the end, but in my case I don't really see when it will go out of scope. I've updated my question with code. So this code shouldn't be much of a problem then?

Comment: Yes and if you have stored the object somewhere (for example in a `std::map`) then you can retrieve the same pointer information from the actual object (or a reference to the object in this case). Just remember that if you cannot reference an object that you create on the heap, then you will have a memory leak, so store or delete before your pointers are out of scope.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's really confusing for fairly newcomers like me. Thanks a bunch =D

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `getEntities` and `getGapless`. If they use `new` to allocate their return values then you'll need to `delete` the returned objects. If they're simply returning pointers to objects that are created elsewhere, then you can think of that as just returning `int`s. I.e. no need to `delete` them when you're done with them.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are ordinary variables. They are not handled in any special way. There's no difference between pointer variables and integer variables in that respect, as there's no difference between between pointer arrays and integer arrays in that respect.

The memory management for all variables in the language is entirely up to you. If you declare a local variable, it is automatically destroyed when control goes out of its block. If you allocate/create objects dynamically, then you have to deallocate/destroy them explicitly. And so on. There's absolutely nothing special about pointers. They are just like any other variables.

Basically, it is not clear why you are even asking this question, since the issue your question seems to address does not really exist. Can you provide an example of what caused you to ask this?

Answer (score 0):

Pointers just hold addresses, the same way 'int' holds an integer. If you instead had an  array of ints and you were using a mutated array based on it, then got rid of the mutated array, the original array stays untouched; here it is really no different.

The values in the mutated array go away, but since they are copies (regardless of whether they are ints or pointers or whatever), it does not affect the original.